# Can domain starting with www be made SPF compliant

Tags: dns, spf

I want to verify a domain for SPF compliant starting with WWW. Can we do so?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Why you might want to do so is a different matter, as it's relatively unusual to send emails from a www-prefixed name, like `user@www.example.com`. Your SPF might look like this in DNS:

```
www IN TXT 86400 "v=spf1 a mx ~all"
```

That says that the host that the A record for the www hostname points at is allowed to send mail, and so is any mail server for the domain. All other hosts get a `softfail` result.

You would normally couple this with a similar record for the domain itself:

```
@ IN TXT 86400 "v=spf1 a mx ~all"
```